# Is there an easy way to shift down cells? - Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently have a program where I insert a value to a cell that already has a value, my desired behavior would be to shift down every value that is from that cell down.

My initial thought was to construct a loop that would assign the current cell value to row+1, but then I would have to subsequently check every cell down.

I came across this related question: [Shift values in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404787/shift-values-in-google-spreadsheet) , but how could I apply from the index the value is being inserted?

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this method did what I needed:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcellsshiftdimension

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("A1:D10");
range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
```

Where range can be the one cell from where you want to shift down. Also specify that the dimension is **ROWS**. Example:

```
sheet.getRange(2,4).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
```

Method above would shift down values from row 2 column 4 (D).

Answer (score 1):

- You want to put the values by the shift down operation using Google Apps Script.
- For example, when a value is put to a cell "A1", you want to put the values to the same column by the shift down operation with a script.

In this answer, I would like to propose to use the method of `autoFill` in Class Range. `autoFill` was added at October 10, 2017. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2017#october_10_2017)

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet
    .getRange("A1")
    .autoFill(sheet.getRange("A1:A"), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.ALTERNATE_SERIES);
}
```

- In this sample script, for example, when `1` is put to a cell "A1" and the function of `myFunction` is run, the cells "A2:A" become `2, 3, 4, 5,,,`.

  - If you want to do the cells "A2:A" to `1, 1, 1, 1, 1,,,`, please modify `SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.ALTERNATE_SERIES` to `SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES`.
- Also, in this sample script, for example, when `=B1` is put to a cell "A1" and the function of `myFunction` is run, the cells "A2:A" become `=B2, =B3, =B4, =B5,,,`.

#### References:

- [autoFill(destination, series)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#autofilldestination-series)
- [Enum AutoFillSeries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/auto-fill-series)

Comment: Thank but thats not what I want to do. Lets say I have column B, with data [A,B,C,D] , and I want to insert value N into cell B. So my desired output would be [A,N,B,C,D] . So it would shift every element down to other cells, keeping the values that I had before. Sorry if my initial question wasn't clear enough!

Comment: @Diego Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: No worries! I didn't know there was an `AutoFill` function, so I learned something new.