# How to shift cells down in specified columns? Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use this script ([Is there an easy way to shift down cells? - Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61220720/is-there-an-easy-way-to-shift-down-cells-google-app-script/64724593#64724593)) to shift 2 cells down at a time in specified columns only when that specified cell is edited. The issue I'm having is that regardless of which cell is edited even outside the column the specified cell shifts. Is there a way to fix this?

this is how I'm using it:`

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange(3,1).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS); sheet.getRange(3,2).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have `onEdit` function somewhere there and this is where you could specify a condition to check only for changes in a specific column:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() === 3) {
      var ss = e.source; 
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var range = sheet.getRange(3,1).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
      sheet.getRange(3,2).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  }
}
```

**What happens here:**

- `onEdit` function runs when any cell in your spreadsheet is edited
- it receives `e` object as an argument, this object has a reference of which cell was edited (`e.range`)
- you can check in which column/row the edit was made by using `e.range.getColumn()`/`e.range.getRow()` in an if condition

**More to read:**

- onEdit trigger: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite
- event objects (`e` in our case): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events
- Range class: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: It works, thank you!! Now I'm trying to figure out how to make it work with another script that affects the same cells :/ seems that it stops my other script that auto-dates cell B4 when Cell A4 is edited. If you have a fix, cool if not no worries! Really appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

Final code after including fix by "A-Change".

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getColumn() === 1) {
      var ss = e.source; 
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var range = sheet.getRange(4,2).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
      sheet.getRange(4,1).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  }
}

{
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "1","2") { //checks that we're on Sheet titled "1"&"2" or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column specified example 1=A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);

nextCell.setValue(new Date());
  
}
}
}
```